# Qsort or Sort on an unordered_set

Tags: c++, sorting, qsort, unordered-set

I have an `unordered_set` called equations. I wasn't to sort or qsort is and this is the line of code im running to do that:

```
qsort(&equations, equations.size(), sizeof(string), strcmp);
```

The error I get is:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::unordered_set<std::basic_string<char> >' to 'void*' 
       for argument '1' to 'void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, __compar_fn_t)'                   
qsort(equations, equations.size(), sizeof(string), strcmp);
```

Comment: A) `unordered_set` cannot be sorted. You'd need to copy its contents into e.g. a `vector`, or use an `std::set` with your own sorting criteria. B) `qsort` is a C function. It won't understand what to do with a user defined type such as a C++ container. You probably want `std::sort`.

Comment: what would be the syntax for sort? @juanchopanza

Comment: Look it up. There are about twenty billion questions on that here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy the `unordered_set` into a `vector` and sort that.

Also use the stl algorithms for sorting:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

Comment: Also note that C++ std::sort is faster than C qsort. One of the main reasons for this is that compile-time binding of comparison fcn is possible in C++, in C qsort, a function pointer is used for the comparison.

Comment: And also note that if OP can use an `std::set`, they wouldn't have to sort.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Back in the day (VS6) I implemented the BWT algorithm and using the STL `sort` was significantly slower than C `qsort`. Out of desperation I tried `stable_sort` and immediately the speeds were comparable.  So, saying one is faster than the other isn't always true - it depends on the data being sorted.

Comment: @Yes, there can always be special cases. But in general, the compile-time binding of the comparison operation is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a `std::set` to store the ordered version of your `std::unordered_set` you could just initialize a new `std::set` by using `std::unordered_set::begin()` and `std::unordered_set::end()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>


int main() 
{
    std::unordered_set<int> unordered = { 9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5 };
    std::set<int> ordered(unordered.begin(), unordered.end());

    std::cout << "Before: ";
    for (auto iter = unordered.begin(); iter != unordered.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "After:  ";
    for (auto iter = ordered.begin(); iter != ordered.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```